# Joining 2 files and comparing them

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

I have two files where I want to use something like a left join that is used in SQL.

`File1`:

```
column1  column2  column3  column4
Ab       Cd       100      Us
Ef       Gh       200      Us
```

`File2`:

```
column1  column2  column3  column4
Ab       Cd       150      Us
```

I want my result to look like below. I need the 3 columns from first file and the corresponding matching value from the second file.

```
column1  column2  column3  column4 
Ab       Cd       100      150
Ef       Gh       200
```

Is it also possible to get difference of the output as `column5`?

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Some clarity would be great . Your output file seems to suggest that you want to replace `Ab             Cd         100          Us`  line from  file 1 with `Ab       Cd      150       Us` from file 2. Is that correct ?

Comment: Hi user3208078 could you clarify what the second line does in your output? It has no matching colums. Still include those lines?

Comment: @user3208078 did you see the question(s) above? please clarify.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. You leave us with a lack of information. Impossible to create a final version of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly, I have to agree the question is on the edge of a purely programmatic one.

At the same time: too tempting and challenging, as an in-between, *not* to answer, and we've answered questions like this before.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3import sys
import sys

files = [[l.split() for l in open(f).readlines()] for f in [sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]]]
for item in files[0]:
    match = [line for line in files[1] if item[:2] == line[:2]]
    if match:
        try:
            calc = abs(int(int(item[2]) - int(match[0][2])))
            print(("\t").join(item[:3])+"\t"+match[0][2]+"\t", calc)
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `analyze.py`
- Run it with the two files as arguments:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/analyze.py <file1> <file2>
  ```

From the examples from your question:

```
$ python3 '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pscript_1.py' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/map/f2' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/map/f1' 
Ab  Cd  150 100  50
```

#### Explanation

The script:

- looks for lines in the two files of which the *first two columns* match:

  ```py
  for item in files[0]:
      match = [line for line in files[1] if item[:2] == line[:2]]
  ```
- of the matching lines, the first two (matching) columns are printed, together with both versions of *the third* column.

  ```py
  if match:
      try:
          calc = abs(int(int(item[2]) - int(match[0][2])))
          print(("\t").join(item[:3])+"\t"+match[0][2]+"\t", calc)
      except TypeError:
          pass
  ```
- The (absolute) difference of the two last columns is calculated (and printed finally) in the line:

  ```py
  calc = abs(int(int(item[2]) - int(match[0][2])))
  ```

*The script assumes:*

- all figures are integers
- You do not want to print out lines which *do not* have matching first two columns
- Each of the lines only have *one possible match* in the other file

Answer (score 0):

Using `join`:

```bsh
join --header -j1 -a1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1 file2
```

If you need the header to report `column4` in the fourth field:

```bsh
join --header -j1 -a1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1 <(awk 'NR == 1 {$3 = "column4"} 1' file2)
```

```bsh
join --header -j1 -a1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1 <(
    awk '
        NR == 1 {
            $3 = "column4"
        }
        1
    ' file2
)
```

This assuming both `file1` and `file2` are sorted on field #1 as in the example.

- `--header`: treats the first line in each file as field headers, printing them without trying to pair them
- `-j1`: joins on field #1 of `file1` and on field #1 of `file2`
- `-a1`: also prints unpairable lines from file `file1`
- `-o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3`: prints field #1, #2 and #3 of `file1` followed by field #3 of `file2`

```
% cat file1
column1  column2  column3  column4
Ab       Cd       100      Us
Ef       Gh       200      Us
% cat file2
column1  column2  column3  column4
Ab       Cd       150      Us
% join --header -j1 -a1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1 file2 
column1 column2 column3 column3
Ab Cd 100 150
Ef Gh 200 
% join --header -j1 -a1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1 <(awk 'NR == 1 {$3 = "column4"} 1' file2)
column1 column2 column3 column4
Ab Cd 100 150
Ef Gh 200
```

Comment: You might be right about OP's intentions, (I am not so sure anymore :), the text in the question seems different from his desired output; what is the last line doing in the output? It has no match) .  On your command I get another output however (missing col 4)

Comment: I removed my answer. I think the question is unclear, and a bit over the edge :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Probably you're right, however we've always answered this kind of questions. I agree most of them are borderline off-topic though. Not sure what I should do. If I vote to close this one I'll have to vote to close most text-processing questions. I know we discussed this on Meta already, but if the community's stance on this kind of questions is changed we should rediscuss the topic again.

Comment: You are also right. For me also counts that if the question is on the edge, but apart from that very well asked, the inclination (if that is correct English) to allow is bigger then if that is not the case. This one seems to be a bit in contradiction with itself...

Comment: @JacobVlijm: you should undelete and ping me so I can upvote!  :P

Comment: @Fabby You know I have a bad character, I cannot resist that :) Done.